# reactiveValues issue

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to merge two uploaded data frames, output it as a table, then being able to download it and reset the inputs, but only get the error: "Error 'by' must match numbers of columns".
I have trouble understanding reactiveValues I guess, since I can't simply call them as data frames in the app...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(readxl)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fileInput('inFile1', 'Choose file'),
  fileInput('inFile2', 'Choose file'),
  actionButton('reset', 'Reset'),
  tableOutput('overlap')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    req(input$inFile1)
    rv$data1 <- readxl::read_xls(input$inFile1$datapath)
  })
  
  observe({
    req(input$inFile2)
    rv$data2 <- readxl::read_xls(input$inFile2$datapath)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    rv$data1 <- NULL
    rv$data2 <- NULL
    reset('inFile1')
    reset('inFile2')
  })
  
  dataframe<-reactive({
    if (!is.null(rv$data1) | !is.null(rv$data2))
      return(NULL)                
    df <- merge(as.data.frame(rv$data1),as.data.frame(rv$data2),by.x = 1,by.y = 1)
    colnames(df) <- c("GeneID",paste0(colnames(rv$data1)[2:ncol(rv$data1)],"_file_1"),
                      paste0(colnames(rv$data2)[2:ncol(rv$data2)],"_file_2"))
    df
  })
  
  overlap1 <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(dataframe()))
      dataframe()
  })
  
  output$overlap <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(overlap1())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I am not sure we can solve this without knowing how the data looks like but I gave it a try. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first glance your reactive expressions look fine to me. And given that error message the error is caused by `merge()`. Taking a closer look there, what strikes me are those `is.null` checks at the top of the `dataframe<-reactive(`. The condition `(!is.null(rv$data1) | !is.null(rv$data2))` means that you are trying to merge two objects that are `NULL` because only then the code wont't stop with `return(NULL)`. If one or both rv-values are "Truthy" the code won't run and all the `reactive` is going to return is `NULL`.

I used `isTruthy()` below. I think it helps in two ways:

1. `isTruthy()` checks if the values contain anything "usable". That way, you do not have to care about how `rv` is initialised. It could be `NA` or `integer(0)` or anything else that is meaningless. `isTruthy` handles all these cases. Merging now only takes place when there are two values with "meaningful" data (note that this does not necessarily mean that the data can be coerced to `data.frame`).
2. It avoids a complicated double negative in the if-statement.

```
  dataframe <- reactive({
    if (isTruthy(rv$data1) && isTruthy(rv$data2)) {
        df <- merge(rv$data1, rv$data2, by.x = 1,by.y = 1)
        colnames(df) <- c("GeneID", paste0(colnames(rv$data1)[2:ncol(rv$data1)], "_file_1"),
                          paste0(colnames(rv$data2)[2:ncol(rv$data2)], "_file_2"))
    } else df <- NULL

    df
  })
```

Final tweak: I removed `as.data.frame` in the `merge` statement because the first thing merge is trying to do is coerce the arguments to a data frame.